# Creating an XML file from XSD from JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm having trouble creating an XML file from XSD using JAXB below is the XSD file used to create it. (Note: Names have been edited due to confidentiality)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Test" type="sel:Test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Option1" type="sel:Option1Type" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
                <xs:element name="Option2" type="sel:Option2Type" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
                <xs:element name="Option3" type="sel:ScreensType" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="ScreensType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="sel:ScreenType" name="Screen" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ScreenType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ScreenData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name1" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name2" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name3" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This is the code I am using to try and create the XML:

```
public void generateXml() throws JAXBException, IOException {

            Test test = new Test();
            ScreensType screens = new ScreensType();
            ScreenType screen = new ScreenType();
            screen.setName1("a");
            screen.setName2("b");
            screen.setName3("c");

            File f = new File("new.xml");
            JAXBContext context= JAXBContext.newInstance("com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.generatedxmlclasses");
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(test, f);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(test, System.out);

        }
```

This is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Test xmlns="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
```

How can I get the code to output the screens and the screen tag along with it's properties, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Based on your code you are barely creating `screen` and `screens` variables and not doing anything with them. You only marshal `test. Did you forget `test.setOption3(screen)` or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create an instance of `Test` and `ScreensType` but never set any of their properties before marshalling them to XML.  Below is the corrected code.

```
public void generateXml() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    Test test = new Test();
    ScreensType screens = new ScreensType();
    test.getOption1OrOption2OrOption3().add(screens);
    ScreenType screen = new ScreenType();
    screen.setName1("a");
    screen.setName2("b");
    screen.setName3("c");
    screens.getScreen().add(screen);

    File f = new File("new.xml");
    JAXBContext context= JAXBContext.newInstance("com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.generatedxmlclasses");
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(test, f);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(test, System.out);
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Test xmlns="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework">
    <Option3>
        <Screen name1="a" name2="b" name3="c"/>
    </Option3>
</Test>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much! I'm new to JAXB so you've been a lot of help.

Comment: @Colin747 - I happy I could help.  BTW, I maintain a Java XML and JSON Binding blog that you may find useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/

Answer (score 3):

After trying for couple of days, eventually i was able to create the xml from xsd properly using the code given below. Hope this helps :

```
           String filename = "<filepath/filename>";

          final Document doc = loadXsdDocument(filename);

       //Find the docs root element and use it to find the targetNamespace
            final Element rootElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
            String targetNamespace = null;
            if (rootElem != null && rootElem.getNodeName().equals("xs:schema")) 
                       {
                targetNamespace = rootElem.getAttribute("targetNamespace");
            }


                        //Parse the file into an XSModel object
            XSModel xsModel = new XSParser().parse(filename);

                        //Define defaults for the XML generation
            XSInstance instance = new XSInstance();
            instance.minimumElementsGenerated = 1;
            instance.maximumElementsGenerated = 1;
            instance.generateDefaultAttributes = true;
            instance.generateOptionalAttributes = true;
            instance.maximumRecursionDepth = 0;
            instance.generateAllChoices = true;
            instance.showContentModel = true;
            instance.generateOptionalElements = true;

                        //Build the sample xml doc
                        //Replace first param to XMLDoc with a file input stream to write to file
            QName rootElement = new QName(targetNamespace, "<xsd file name>");
            XMLDocument sampleXml = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult(System.out), true, 4, null);
            instance.generate(xsModel, rootElement, sampleXml);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) 
                {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Document loadXsdDocument(String inputName) {
        final String filename = inputName;

        final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            final File inputFile = new File(filename);
            doc = builder.parse(inputFile);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // throw new ContentLoadException(msg);
        }

        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: This answer' sample code uses classes from the [JLibs project](https://santhosh-tekuri.github.io/jlibs/xsd/XSInstance.html).