# How to create XML file from XSD on the incoming records in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a spreadsheet based on which I have to generate an xml file. That file should respect a particular XSD structure and I have to do from Java.

The XML mapping is not working in excel because of "list of lists " issue.
what would be an ideal approach in java to create, dom parser or jaxb?
Any reference is helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an XML file from XSD from JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147428/creating-an-xml-file-from-xsd-from-jaxb)

Comment: What is the “list of lists” issue?

Comment: Personally, I would do this in XSLT.